# What tests should I create for unit testing a library that receives and parses XML?

Tags: unit-testing, tdd, nunit

I'm trying to get into the groove of TDD and I've decided to refactor my entire class library project that parses XML it receives from an exposed API.

Now I'm stuck on what tests I should have.

Can you recommend some tests I should have and also how to identify what I need to test for the future, basic rule of thumb?

Thanks!

```
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace SharpDIC.Tests
{
    [TestFixture]
    class MemberTests
    {
        [Test]
        public void Member_Should_Have_Required_Information()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible for you to share the public interface of your xml parsing library?

Comment: @Sergio: I am slightly confused. Do you want to write a new xml parsing library using TDD or you want to write unit tests for the existing library so as to refactor it? Please clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually start with a test that just creates the object. This gets the ball rolling and gets your thinking about dependencies going. After that, think about the simplest thing you can do with your code. Maybe it's parsing the empty string and doing nothing at all (or throwing an exception). That's a valid - and valuable - test. Now you've got a skeleton that does nothing and adding the individual features test-first shouldn't be too difficult, since you have an existing feature list.

Answer (score 0):

You should write unit tests where each test reveals some existing behavior of the already implemented code. One additional thing could be to have 100% code coverage of your xml parsing library before you start refactoring it. I could not comment much without looking at the public interface of your xml library.

On a side note,

Unit Tests acts as a safety net which helps you to catch any breacking functional changes done during refactoring. Unit tests will enable you for refactoring.